# Unity Splash Screen not showing when run in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, screen, splash-screen

For some reason when I build my Unity game to my iPhone 5s to test it out, the background will be gray and the Unity splash screen will not show up and then it will flash the unity logo very briefly (1/10 second), then the game starts. Sometimes the logo won't even come up and just have that gray background until my game starts. This obviously looks awful and I don't want to put my game on the iOS App Store this way (also there are legal issues with it not showing up). This problem has persisted for a while now. I'm using Unity 5.3.4f1 and Xcode 7.3.1 currently, but this issue has gone on for previous versions of Unity and Xcode. I can create a brand new Unity project and build it to iOS and the splash screen works perfectly. I've built my game to Android and the Unity splash screen works exactly how it's supposed to so it seems to be an iOS specific problem with my project. I've searched on how to fix this to no avail, so any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you